# Invite Facebook friends to become my LinkedIn connections?

Tags: facebook, linkedin

I am looking for a way to send LinkedIn connection requests to my Facebook friends.

I do remember seeing some method year and half ago, which allowed such similar cross-connection, but I'm not able to find it now.

Is there any way/method to sync (or send invitations to) Facebook friends?

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to share contacts between Facebook and LinkedIn.
But using Yahoo Mail you can invite your Facebook friends to connect on LinkedIn.
Below is the steps you can follow:

- Create a Yahoo! Account (if you don’t already have one).
- Login to your Yahoo! Mail account.
- Go to “Contacts”.
- Click on “Import Now” under Import your Contacts from other accounts to Yahoo!
- Choose “Facebook”.
- Enter your “Facebook e-mail and password” (that you normally log into Facebook with).
- Log into LinkedIn.
- Go to “Contacts”.
- Click on the “Imported Contacts” tab in the Contacts tool bar.
- Click on “+Add More Contacts” at the bottom of your Imported Contacts List.
- Enter your “Yahoo e-mail address & password” & click on “Find Contacts”.
- You will be taken to Yahoo, enter your “Yahoo e-mail address & Password”.
- “Accept” the Automatic Login Terms of Service.
- LinkedIn will now let you select specific or all your Facebook (and now Yahoo) accounts to invite to connect with you on LinkedIn.

If you choose not to invite all your Facebook and Yahoo connections, their addresses will remain in your Imported Contacts list that you can access later.